# Typescript type inference is different between utility type Extract and conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a litte bit confusing when using utility Extract<T, U> and conditional type as below:

```
export type NumberOrString = number | string;
export type ConditionalType = NumberOrString extends string ? string : never;
//          ^? type ConditionalType = never
export type ExtractedType = Extract<NumberOrString, string>;
//          ^? type ExtractedType = string
```

Can anyone explain for me why the `ConditionalType` and `ExtractedType` have different type although the behind type definition of Extract is same as ConditionalType (type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never)?

Comment: When you hover over in the playground the definition is actually `type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never` which would translate to `NumberOrString extends string ? NumberOrString : never` which tells me that there's more things going on under the hood and the shorthand description is not entirely accurate. It seems to be the opposite of `Omit<...>` which shows similar behaviour if you try to use its suggested definition directly rather than the utility type itself so they might work differently than the playground might suggest

Comment: From the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types): "When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type." Here's an [example](https://tsplay.dev/w1n9AN) using your question data.